# Uniform confidence band for parametric model

Tags: confidence-interval

Lets say we have a parametric model $\mathcal{F} = \{\text{distribution functions }F_{\theta} \;|\; \theta \in \Theta\}$ and a point estimate $\hat{\theta}$ of the corresponding parameter $\theta$ together with a confidence interval denoted by $[l,u]$.
Clearly (assume $F_{\theta}$ is strictly monotone) $F_{\hat{\theta}}$ is an estimator for the distribution function an $[F_{l},F_{r}]$ a confidence set.

However I'm wondering, is this confidence set uniform or pointwise? In the sense that either
$$P\left(F(x) \in [F_{l}(x), F_{r}(x)] \;\;\; \forall x\right)=1-\alpha$$
or
$$P\left(F(x) \in [F_{l}(x), F_{r}(x)]\right)=1-\alpha \;\;\; \forall x$$

The reason for asking is because I want to test the performance of the non-parametric, uniform confidence band (on the basis of the EDF) with a parametric one.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: In what sense is "$[F_l, F_r]$" a "confidence set"?  You seem to be equating estimators and confidence intervals for parameters with estimators and confidence intervals for values of distribution functions at arbitrary numbers $x$, but the two have little to do with each other.

Comment: If we fix x and $\theta \mapsto F_{\theta}(x)$ is stricly monotone, we can conclude $[F_{l}(x),F_{r}(x)]$ is a confidence interval for $F(x)$. So it is a pointwise confidence set.
Now my question is, is it also a uniform (or simultaneous) confidence set? If not, how to make one?

Comment: Your first assertion is incorrect: the fact that $[l,r]$ is a confidence interval for $\theta$ tells you next to nothing (in general) about $F_\theta(x)$.

Comment: I think it does. Because of monotinicity, which I assumed, the events (for fixed $x$) $\{\theta \in [l,r]\}$ and $\{F_{\theta}(x) \in [F_l(x),F_r(x)]\}$ are identical.

Comment: Could you tell us what, specifically, you mean by "monotonicity"?

Comment: For fixed $x$, $\theta \mapsto F_{\theta}(x)$ is strictly increasing or decreasing.
In which case $\theta \in [l,r]$ iff $F_{\theta}(x) \in [F_l(x),F_r(x)]$. So I'm pretty sure this leads a pointwise confidence interval, as I defined in the OP. i.e. in the sense that the $\forall x$ is outside the probability.

Now I'm wondering does this also yield a uniform (or simultaneous) confidence band or enveloppe. If not (of if yes), what are other methods to construct such bands?